# Outlook not rendering correctly on mobile for html email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an HTML email I am building and am having an issue with columns NOT stacking when on mobile. Everything else renders fine. I am using `display: block` as the class to have them stack on smaller screen sizes. I am only having this issue on OUTLOOK mobile. Every other client is rendering and stacking just fine. Is there an outlook-specific condition I need to add for Outlook to render `display: block`? Attached is the issue on Outlook mobile.

[image]

```css
            .stack .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<td class="column column-1"
                                                                                                                                            width="50%"
                                                                                                                                            style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;">
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="image_block block-2"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td class="pad"
                                                                                                                                                        style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:5px;">
                                                                                                                                                        <div class="alignment"
                                                                                                                                                            align="center"
                                                                                                                                                            style="line-height:10px">
                                                                                                                                                            <img src="https://image.marketing.fiskerinc.com/lib/fe2f11727364047f721373/m/1/baf9400c-f3b0-4686-9195-8fbc3f2bf60d.png"
                                                                                                                                                                style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 75px; max-width: 100%;"
                                                                                                                                                                width="75">
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="paragraph_block block-3"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td
                                                                                                                                                        class="pad">
                                                                                                                                                        <div
                                                                                                                                                            style="color:#000000;direction:ltr;font-family:Fisker-Bold,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:center;mso-line-height-alt:19.2px;">
                                                                                                                                                            <div
                                                                                                                                                                style="margin: 0;">
                                                                                                                                                                <b>Service Appointment</b>
                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="paragraph_block block-4"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td class="pad"
                                                                                                                                                        style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                                                                                                                        <div
                                                                                                                                                            style="color:#000000;direction:ltr;font-family:Fisker-Regular,Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:center;mso-line-height-alt:19.2px;">
                                                                                                                                                            <p
                                                                                                                                                                style="margin: 0;">
                                                                                                                                                                [Service Appointment Date]
                                                                                                                                                            </p>
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                        <td class="column column-1"
                                                                                                                                            width="50%"
                                                                                                                                            style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-weight: 400; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; border-top: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px;">
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="image_block block-2"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td class="pad"
                                                                                                                                                        style="width:100%;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:5px;">
                                                                                                                                                        <div class="alignment"
                                                                                                                                                            align="center"
                                                                                                                                                            style="line-height:10px">
                                                                                                                                                            <img src="https://image.marketing.fiskerinc.com/lib/fe2f11727364047f721373/m/1/baf9400c-f3b0-4686-9195-8fbc3f2bf60d.png"
                                                                                                                                                                style="display: block; height: auto; border: 0; width: 75px; max-width: 100%;"
                                                                                                                                                                width="75">
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="paragraph_block block-3"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td
                                                                                                                                                        class="pad">
                                                                                                                                                        <div
                                                                                                                                                            style="color:#000000;direction:ltr;font-family:Fisker-Bold,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:center;mso-line-height-alt:19.2px;">
                                                                                                                                                            <div
                                                                                                                                                                style="margin: 0;">
                                                                                                                                                                <b>Service Appointment</b>
                                                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                            <table
                                                                                                                                                class="paragraph_block block-4"
                                                                                                                                                width="100%"
                                                                                                                                                border="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellpadding="0"
                                                                                                                                                cellspacing="0"
                                                                                                                                                role="presentation"
                                                                                                                                                style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;">
                                                                                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                                                                                    <td class="pad"
                                                                                                                                                        style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                                                                                                                        <div
                                                                                                                                                            style="color:#000000;direction:ltr;font-family:Fisker-Regular,Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:0px;line-height:120%;text-align:center;mso-line-height-alt:19.2px;">
                                                                                                                                                            <p
                                                                                                                                                                style="margin: 0;">
                                                                                                                                                                [Service Appointment Date]
                                                                                                                                                            </p>
                                                                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                                                                        </td>
```

Comment: You haven't given enough to reproduce this. Usually in email we have to look at the full thing, but feel free to change text to something generic.

Comment: Which is why I sent a screen shot as I am only having an issue in Outlook browsers

Comment: We need more code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Well Outlook is tricky in that matter, because it's not using standard HTML in favour of their own VML. Anyway, it seems that Outlook supports display property partially. Check https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=display for further explanation and supported properties.